# how to make clickable circles using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

Basically, I'm trying to create a game in which circles will spawn on a canvas and the user has to click them as fast as possible. The circles should spawn randomly on the canvas and have a certain radius. Once the user clicks a circle, they are awarded points based on the time it took them to click the circle (less time = more points). After the user clicks the circle, it disappears, and another circle randomly spawns somewhere on the canvas, and the user keeps doing this until 100 circles are clicked overall.

The whole point of this game is to help improve accuracy and reflex for FPS games. I decided I would create a game like this to help myself mainly, and for anyone else because I couldn't find a game like this online that fit my needs.

Anyway, here's the code for the game I have so far. If anyone could help me in the direction of further developing this game or even completing it, it would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```js
var mainCanvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
var mainContext = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasWidth = mainCanvas.width;
var canvasHeight = mainCanvas.height;

function spawnTarget() {
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  text-align: center;
}

#header {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  margin: 64px auto;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 128px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

#myCanvas {
  width: 1800px;
  height: 900px;
  border: 4px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aim Practice</title>
 <link href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Aim Practice</h1>
 </div>
 <div id="container">
   <canvas id="myCanvas">
   </canvas>
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what about http://p5js.org/ ?

Comment: does my answer help? if not, please comment as to what else you need.

Answer (score 0):

because the circles won't be actual DOM elements, you will have to listen for `click` events on the canvas, and compare the `screenX` and `screenY` on the click event to the canvas coordinates of he circle in question. Remember to add in the offset of the canvas relative to the screen. You will also have to manually calculate whether the click is inside the circle or not.